# Error: 'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both 'material/date_picker_theme.dart' & 'flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'

Tags: android, flutter

I could not build my project after upgrading my flutter. I upgraded the flutter from 3.0.1 to 3.10.0
The debug console is showing:

```
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/form_builder_extra_fields-8.3.0/lib/src/fields/form_builder_cupertino_date_time_picker.dart:6:1: Error: 'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart' and 'package:flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'.
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya/flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya.dart';
flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya.dart:1
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya-2.0.0/lib/flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya.dart:7:1: Error: 'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart' and 'package:flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'.
import 'src/datetime_picker_theme.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya-2.0.0/lib/flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya.dart:200:31: Error: 'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart' and 'package:flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'.
        this.theme = theme ?? DatePickerTheme(),
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_chips_input-2.0.0/lib/src/chips_input.dart:87:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'ChipsInputState' is missing implementations for these members:
 - TextInputClient.didChangeInputControl
 - TextInputClient.insertContent
 - TextInputClient.performSelector
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class ChipsInputState<T> extends State<ChipsInput<T>>

      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1158:8: Context: 'TextInputClient.didChangeInputControl' is defined here.
  void didChangeInputControl(TextInputControl? oldControl, TextInputControl? newControl) {}
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1117:8: Context: 'TextInputClient.insertContent' is defined here.
  void insertContent(KeyboardInsertedContent content) {}
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1179:8: Context: 'TextInputClient.performSelector' is defined here.

  void performSelector(String selectorName) {}
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My packages imported are:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.8.0
  firebase_core: ^2.13.0
  firebase_storage: ^11.2.1
  file_picker: ^5.2.6
  datetime_picker_formfield: 
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.1
  overlay_support: ^2.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.7.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.6.1
  flutter_facebook_auth:
  intl: ^0.17.0
  csc_picker: 
  google_sign_in:
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  get:
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.0
  geolocator: 
  flutter_map:
  flutter_map_marker_cluster:
  http:
  geocoding: ^2.1.0
  flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
  map_location_picker: ^1.1.0
```

My flutter doctor

- [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version
  10.0.19044.2965], locale  en-US)
- [√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
- [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc2)
- [√] Chrome - develop for the web
- [√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
  (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.0.0)
- [√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
- [√] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
- [√] Connected device (4 available)
- [√] Network resources

I have tried cleaning project, upgrading pub packages and flutter pub cache repair but it is still the same. Any other solutions I can use?

Answer (score 13):

## USE UPDATED PLUGIN

### REPLACE OLD :

```
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.1
```

### TO NEW ONE :

```
  flutter_datetime_picker_plus: ^2.1.0
```

### EXAMPLE IMPORT

#### import

```
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker_plus/flutter_datetime_picker_plus.dart' as datatTimePicker;
```

Comment: I struggled for a few hours until I saw this. Works like a charm

Answer (score 4):

I have solved it by using flutter pub upgrade --major-versions and removing some packages, so that it gets `These packages are no longer being depended on: - flutter_chips_input 2.0.0 - flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya 2.0.0 - flutter_touch_spin 2.0.0 - google_maps_webservice 0.0.20-nullsafety.5`

Answer (score 2):

I find a very simple way to solve this problem.

Just Do it in the file where you find this problem

```
Error: 'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart' and 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'.
flutter_datetime_picker.dart:6
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart';
datetime_picker_theme.dart:1
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

: Error: 'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart' and 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'.
flutter_datetime_picker.dart:199
        this.theme = theme ?? DatePickerTheme(),
```

**change this,**
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

**to this,**
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide DatePickerTheme;

Answer (score 1):

In your `ChipsInput` widget you used 2 imports that conflict with each other. It is conflicting where you call `this.theme = theme ?? DatePickerTheme()` because it doesn't know which import to use since they have the same name.

You need to either remove `import 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart'`
or `import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'`

Alternatively you can try to rename 1 of the imports using `as` like this:

```
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart' as example

example.DatePickerTheme()
```

Comment: Hi, but i don't think i imported the package or used it for any parts during the development. I could not find where to fix this.